# must i have FMS to publish a stream from my camera?

Tags: php, publish, rtmp, flash-media-server, live-streaming

i am building an live streaming website and i am use
1- FMS 
2- Apache webserver

i have made the subcriber and i works well .
but i need to build the publisher to allow users to broadcast thier stream from thier cameras.

i have tested a publisher which was build using actionscript and it didn't work untill i have installed the fms on my localhost , but i need a publisher which any user can use in his web browser .

my publisher :

```
   protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void 
        { 
            connection = new NetConnection(); 
            connection.connect("rtmp:/live"); 
            connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,onConnected); 

        } 
   private function setupVideo():void 
        { 
            //setting up outgoing devices 
            camera = Camera.getCamera(); 
            camera.setMode(640,480,30); 
            mic = Microphone.getMicrophone(); 

            //setting up outgoing Stream 
            outStream = new NetStream(connection); 
            outStream.attachCamera(camera); 
            outStream.attachAudio(mic); 
            outStream.publish("EraMaX-Live"); 

            //setting up outgoing video & attach outgoing devices 
            outVideo = new Video(); 
            outVideo.attachCamera(camera);  
            //setting up incomming Stream 
            inStream = new NetStream(connection); 
            inStream.play("EraMaX-Live"); 

            //setting up incomming video & attach incoming Stream 
            inVideo = new Video(); 
            inVideo.attachNetStream(inStream); 

            //wrap video object 
            outVideoWrapper = new UIComponent(); 
            outVideoWrapper.addChild(outVideo); 
            addElement(outVideoWrapper); 

            inVideoWrapper = new UIComponent(); 
            inVideoWrapper.addChild(inVideo); 
            addElement(inVideoWrapper); 
            inVideoWrapper.move(400,0); 
            //setting up incomming video 

        }
```

so my question must i have FMS to publish a stream from my camera to my website ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stream live video, you need a streaming server. Not definitely FMS, you also can use Red5, Wowza, or even open source solutions such as RTMPD or RTMPLite.